# Calculating transition matrix for $P(X_{20}=2|X_{10}=2)$

Tags: markov-chains, transition-matrix

Deduce the general form of $P^n$ in terms of $n$ and use this answer to calculate $P(X_{20}=2|X_{10}=2)$

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0&0\\ \frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0&0 \\ 0&0&\frac{2}{3}&\frac{1}{3} \\ 0&0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Its obvious that when I split the matrices into blocks, it produces the following because each row must sum to one

$$P^n=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0&0\\ \frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0&0 \\ 0&0&\ \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n&1-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n \\ 0&0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

It is shown by the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation that
$$P_{ij}^{m+n}=P(X_{m+n}=j|X_0=i)$$

Now $P(X_{20}=2|X_{10}=2)$ = $P(X_{10}=2|X_{0}=2)$, however the result shows that
$$P(X_{10}=2|X_{0}=2)=\frac{2^{10}}{3^{10}}$$

I thought that $i=2, j=2$ would mean the intersection at the second row and second column which is $\frac{1}{2}$, however this is not the case. May some kindly explain this inconsistency in my reasoning for me!

Comment: Maybe the states are $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ rather than $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$?

Comment: What is the involved process $X$?

Comment: @angryavian genius! I didn't look to notice that, this seems to have been the reason. Thank you!